# What will be the Test Class for this Pie Chart?

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
public with sharing class PackageBuilderExtenssion 
{ 
public PackageBuilderExtenssion(ApexPages.StandardController std) {
        sc=std;
        id=std.getId(); //Controller Id         

        groupedResults  = [SELECT product__r.family, Sum(quantity__c)  
                           FROM package_item__c where package__c=:id
                           Group by product__r.family]; //PeiChart Result Query
    }
public List<PieChartData> getPieData() {
        List<PieChartData> data = new List<PieChartData>();

        for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {            
            if(ar.get('family')!=null)
            {
                data.add(new PieChartData(
                    String.ValueOf(ar.get('family')),
                    Double.ValueOf(ar.get('expr0'))
                ));
            }    
        }      
        return data;
    }

    public class PieChartData {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public Decimal data { get; set; }
        public PieChartData(String name, Decimal data) {
            this.name = name;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context, as your question is just a code dump. [Read here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions on SFSE.

Answer (score 1):

The test class will need to:

- insert several `Product` objects and several `package_item__c` objects related to those
- create your controller extension as described in [Testing Custom Controllers and Controller Extensions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm)
- invoke the `getPieData` method
- assert that the number of `PieChartData` items and the individual field values are correct (based on the data you inserted); a clean way to do that is shown below

Example:

```
List<PieChartData> expecteds = new List<PieChartData>{
    new PieChartData(..., ...),
    new PieChartData(..., ...),
    new PieChartData(..., ...),
    ...
};
List<PieChartData> actuals = controller.getPieData();
System.assertEquals(expecteds, actuals);
```